# How to add a Calendar event to my Layout?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with Calendar java class. I create an event in my Calendar on the MainActivity. How could I add this event to my Layout from the MainActivity.java?

Thanks

Comment: http://karanbalkar.com/2014/03/add-event-to-calendar-in-android/

Comment: i saw this code before but i don't know how to see my event in the layout once i submitted the date.